# Generic maker function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I am trying to write a template function which creates a type generically using any given "maker" function.  For example, the function should be able to create an `int` using `std::make_unique`, `std::make_shared`, or `std::make_optional`.

I am pretty sure the solution requires use of a template template.  Here is my attempt, but this doesn't compile.

```
#include <memory>
#include <optional>

template <template <typename, typename ...> typename Maker>
auto create(int a, int b)
{
    return Maker<int>(a + b);
}

int main()
{
    auto a = create<std::make_optional>(1, 2);
    auto b = create<std::make_unique>(3, 4);
    auto c = create<std::make_shared>(10, 20);
        
    return 0;
}
```

In this example, my intent is to write a function which, given two integers, will add them together and return either a `std::unique_ptr<int>`, `std::shared_ptr<int>`, or `std::optional<int>` containing the sum of the two `int` parameters.

Comment: `std::make_optional` is not a type template. It is function template. So your `create` can't accept it since it expects type template.

Comment: And what's wrong with `auto a = std::make_optional(1 + 2);` ?

Comment: @pptaszni Imaging my create function is not so trivial as adding two numbers.  I want it to be able to use the same algorithm to create the same type containing in different containers depending on the application.

Comment: Hmm, this kind of call style would be acceptable: `auto opt = generate(1, 2, [](auto arg){ return std::make_optional(arg); });` ?

Comment: If the problem is some more complex function than just adding and you have to write `std::make_optional` or whatever else anyways as template parameter, why not just use a lambda (or even a function??) and do something like `auto a = std::make_optional([](int a, int b) { return a * b; }(1, 2));`?

Comment: "Imaging my create function is not so trivial as adding two numbers. I want it to be able to use the same algorithm to create the same type containing in different containers depending on the application" then you would pass "maker" (in your case something that adds two integers) to your template function. But the reason you want to pass `std::make_optional` or `std::make_unique` rather than directly calling it is unclear

Comment: in your example its not the `Maker` that computes `a +b` but `create` does that. Exchanging `+` with some arbitrary `g(a,b)` is rather simple, and once you have that you can simply pass the result directly to `std::make_optional` (or one of the others), would that be ok? What I am at is: Do you really need one template that works with either of `std::make_optional`, `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` ? Or would 3 seperate methods be fine?

Comment: Is `std::make_optional(foo(a, b))` good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the three function templates matches `template <typename, typename ...> typename Maker` because thats a type template.

Function templates are actually rather limited in what you can do with them.

It might be that I misunderstand the question. However, I am suggesting to change the angle on your issue, and write three seperate functions and instead of passing the `std::make_xx` function template you pass the operation used for the initializer:

```
#include <memory>
#include <optional>
#include <functional>

template <typename G>
auto create_optional(int a, int b, G&& g) { return std::make_optional<int>(g(a,b)); }
template <typename G>
auto create_unique(int a, int b, G&& g) { return std::make_unique<int>(g(a,b)); }
template <typename G>
auto create_shared(int a, int b, G&& g) { return std::make_shared(g(a,b)); }


int main()
{
    auto a = create_optional(1,2,std::plus<>{});      // 1+2
    auto b = create_unique(2,3,std::minus<>{});       // 2+3
    auto c = create_shared(3,4,std::multiplies<>{});  // 3+4
}
```

Note how the standard library uses type templates, `plus`, `minus` and `multiplies` for generic callables that are supposed to be passed to other generic functions. If you wanted to implement your initial approach you would also switch to types as template parameters. For example as suggested in comments, pass lambdas that wrap the "makers" (such that the type of the lambda is your functions template argument).